# Insert values from active record into a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this:

```
produtos = LineItem.select('codigosku, quantity').where("cart_id = #{session[:cart_id] } ")
```

I need to insert the result of this select (produto variable), here:

```
message = Hash.new
      message = { 
        "tem:carrinho" => {"gpa:CEP" => params[:cep],
                      "gpa:CNPJ" => 'doc', 
                      "gpa:IdCampanha" => 1111, 
                      "gpa:Produtos" => {"gpa:DadosListaProdutoCarrinhoDTO" => 
                          {

                               HERE! VALUES OF "PRODUTOS VARIABLE"


                          }
                        }
                      }
                }
```

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

create your array:

```
line_items_array = line_items.map{|li| li.attributes }
```

Then insert the array within your hash.

Comment: how to insert this array into the hash? Sorry for the stupid question... :-(

Answer (score 1):

like in apneadiving example, use map to create an array from the produtos data; use `attributes` to return all data (it is a hash) from your selected data

```
message = { 
  "tem:carrinho" => {
    "gpa:CEP" => params[:cep],
    "gpa:CNPJ" => 'doc', 
    "gpa:IdCampanha" => 1111, 
    "gpa:Produtos" => {
      "gpa:DadosListaProdutoCarrinhoDTO" => produtos.map { |item| item.attributes } 
    } 
  }
}
```

or if you need to be more specific about the keys in the produtos and append it after initialization

```
# initialize the Produtos to nil
message = { 
  "tem:carrinho" => {
    "gpa:CEP" => params[:cep],
    "gpa:CNPJ" => 'doc', 
    "gpa:IdCampanha" => 1111, 
    "gpa:Produtos" => nil
  }
}        

# build an array of DadosListaProdutoCarrinhoDTO
list = produtos.map do |item| 
  {
    "gpa:DadosListaProdutoCarrinhoDTO" => {
      "codigosku" => item.codigosku, 
      "quantity" => item.quantity
    }
  }
end

# set the Produtos key to an array of DadosListaProdutoCarrinhoDTO
message["tem:carrinho"].merge!({ "gpa:Produtos" => list })
```

Comment: please, one more info! I just want the "codigosku" => item.codigosku, "quantity" => item.quantity being repeated, inside of the "gpa:DadosListaProdutoCarrinhoDTO" tag!!! Is that possible? Best!

Comment: you are working with 2 data structures hash and array, there is no magic going on, you should be able to construct the desired output based on examples above